# ImportError with absolute and relative imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having trouble importing with a very simple file structure.

My file structure looks like this:

```
project/
  ...
  project.py
  helper.py
  __init__.py
  ...
```

Within project.py is the class I am trying to import in helper

```
#project.py

class MyAPIOne():
...

class MyAPITwo():
...
```

```
#helper.py

import MyAPIOne

if __name__ == "__main__":
  api = MyApiOne()
  ...
```

When running with `python3 helper.py`:

If I keep the absolute import `import MyAPIOne` I recieve `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyAPIOne'`

If I change it to a relative import `from . import MyAPIOne` I receive `ImportError: cannot import name 'MyAPIOne'`

I have also experimented with appended to `sys.path` various directories, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this script from the `project` folder, you can alter your import the following way: `from project import MyAPIOne`.
Also, you can add this folder to your `PYTHONPATH` env variable.

Upd: to add some folder to PYTHONPATH you can ran

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

Answer (score -1):

main file can import all the files,  but main file can't be imported by other files.

once file mentioned with **__name__ = "__main__"**,  then it becomes main file. so helper.py is acts as main file. it can't be imported.

Comment: Hi - I am actually importing from project.py - think my filenames might be a bit unclear in the example!

Comment: yes, i thought it was the issue,  but what i have mentioned as answer, you can able to check in different ways to solve your issue.